# Pattern Matcher for Java

Tags: java, regex, csv

How to give this pattern in java pattern matcher

```
"([^"]*)"|(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(?=,|$)
```

I am getting compilation error.

My code is,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^"]*)"|(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(?=,|$));  \\Getting syntax error here
```

Please resolve

Comment: Use: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^\"]*)\"|(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(?=,|$)");`

Comment: Is the first quote part of the Regular Expresion?

Answer (score 2):

double Quote Chatacter in your patten should always be preceeded by a backslash like this..

\"

Answer (score 2):

You didn't escape the `"` quotes INSIDE the pattern, leading to them prematurely terminating the pattern's string:

```
"([^"]*)"|(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(?=,|$)
    ^---^--
```

Try

```
"([^\"]*)\"|(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(?=,|$)
    ^----^---
```

instead. Note the backslashes.

Comment: My input string is : LineUHC,adhoc1,,"Arnett, Hostal",5165 cCarty Ln,Lafatte,IN,4792205,,,,,, The expected output is String array of all the 14 values in the input string. Also, double quotes in the inputs must be retained. But the pattern is not working well

Comment: The text is irrelevant. Your Java code is broken because of the syntax errors.

Comment: To be simple, I need a pattern that takes values between commas. If there are double quotes, it should read whatever in between the two quotes.

Comment: Example Input : Name,Number,"Address,Place"                                          Expected Output: Value1: Name, Value2: Number, Value3 : "Address,Place"